# JavaFX animation on raspberry pi

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, transition, javafx-8

I have a question, is it possible to do an animation in JavaFX on the Raspberry Pi?
I am using this code:

```
public class PhotoRotateTransition
{
private ImageView imageView;

public PhotoRotateTransition(ImageView imageView, Image img){
    this.imageView = imageView;
    this.changeImage(img);
}

private void changeImage(Image img){
    this.imageView.setRotate(0);
    RotateTransition rotate1 = this.rotate1();
    rotate1.play();
    rotate1.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            imageView.setRotate(270);
            imageView.setImage(img);
            RotateTransition rotate2 = rotate2();
            rotate2.play();
        }
    });
}

private RotateTransition rotate1(){

    RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(500), this.imageView);
    rotateTransition.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    rotateTransition.setToAngle(90);
    rotateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rotateTransition.setCycleCount(1);
    return rotateTransition;
}

private RotateTransition rotate2(){
    RotateTransition rotateTransition2 = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(500), this.imageView);
    rotateTransition2.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    rotateTransition2.setToAngle(360);
    rotateTransition2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rotateTransition2.setCycleCount(1);
    return rotateTransition2;
 }
}
```

This code works on my mac, but the image on the raspberry pi just changes without a transition.
Can someone help me with this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations do work in the Raspberry Pi, for sure.

The problem with *your* animation is it's using a rotation over the Y axis of the image, which means it is rotated "out" of the screen. And for that you need 3D rendering capabilities...

On the Raspberry Pi and other embedded devices, 3D is an experimental feature in JavaFX.

To make this feature work you just need to enable 3D with this command line option:

```
-Dcom.sun.javafx.experimental.embedded.3d=true
```

And then your animation will work.